# in the geopoly extensions what is the unit of the radius for a regular polygon and how to convert that to miles and kilometers?

Tags: sqlite

SQLite has some interesting extensions [Geopoly](https://www.sqlite.org/geopoly.html). In this library there are functions for testing polygons. One basic function :

```
/*
** Function:   geopoly_regular(X,Y,R,N)
**
** Construct a simple, convex, regular polygon centered at X, Y
** with circumradius R and with N sides.
*/
```

In one of the examples they produce some basic shapes, however, when X/Y are latitude and longitude then the units for the radius is questionable. (side note, N also get's fuzzy on large R.)

So give that R is a circumradius which means it unit is probably based on the lat/long. How do I compute something meaningful?

The source for the extension is [here](https://sqlite.org/src/file?name=ext/rtree/geopoly.c&ci=tip)

UPDATE

I think I have it... The lat/long coordinates are are in "degrees decimal" and needed to be converted to radians so that. However, the code, even though it seems to work it still has some problems.

According to [this](http://www.meridianoutpost.com/resources/etools/calculators/calculator-latitude-longitude-distance.php?) website the distance between these points is 16.44 miles which means a radius of 17 should work. but does not.

```
select geopoly_contains_point(
   geopoly_regular(
             26.122438* 0.01745327  --lat convert DEG2RAD
             ,-80.137314* 0.01745327  --long convert DEG2RAD
             ,19.0/3959  -- radius convert miles to RAD
             ,200 -- polygon sides
          )
       , 26.103039* 0.01745327 -- target lat convert DEG2RAD
       , -80.401382* 0.01745327 -- target long convert DEG2RAD
   )
   ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is still valid, however, the answer is in the negative. The geopoly functions seem to be 2D where distances between two points on earth are based on curves and 3D.

One probably needs to use the ‘haversine’ formula and there are plenty of examples of that.

Comment: mongo has something called `2dsphere`, anything like that for sqlite?